# Error Launching android studio in ubuntu 16.04 using wine

Tags: android, android-studio, jvm, ubuntu-16.04

I am using android studio 2.2.2 windows version in ubuntu 16.04 using wine.(because of ubuntu version stuck in build gradle)

When i start android studio .exe file it gives an error:

```
"Error Launching Android Studio" : "The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle) does not point to a valid JVM Installation.
```

Also Try the below steps:

1) Sudo nano /etc/environment : Add JAVA_HOME to my system java location

2) Install latest java version 9 & 8

3) Restart system many times.

Please suggest best answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: already tried many times

Comment: why do you use the windows version in the first place?

Comment: ubuntu version stuck in build gradle

Comment: then let's try to fix this. the native version for linux runs a lot better than emulating with wine

Comment: sure, why not i already tried my best all the possible ways then choose last option to use .exe file using wine

Comment: wine?? are you sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: @pskink : Wine is a compatibility layer for running Windows applications on Linux. Applications are run at full speed without the need of cpu emulation. Wine does not require Microsoft Windows, however it can use native system dll files in place of its own if they are available.

Comment: you are on ubuntu linux (just like me), then fix your `"stuck in build gradle"` problem instead of running wine

Comment: you can suggest the way to resolve it.

Comment: to resolve what? "stuck in build gradle" does not say anything

Answer (score -1):

You can use LINUX version of android studio: android-studio-ide-145.3537739-linux.zip

Comment: already tried many times then i choose windows version using wine

Comment: I am sorry, I am newbie.

Comment: np. but remember for the future